# Concatenate TStringStream

Tags: sql-server, delphi, blob, delphi-xe7

I would like to concatenate some TStringStreams into one Stream.

I have some blob (varbinary(max)) fields in SQL Server and and I want to create a stream from all the rows then save it to a file.

```
var
  // MSWord: Variant;
  i: Int32;
  sA: TStringStream;
  sP: TStringStream;
  s: TStringStream;
  // fString: TStrings;
begin
  sA := TStringStream.Create;
  s := TStringStream.Create;
  sP := TStringStream.Create;
  try
    with DateED do
    begin
      BlobField.SaveToStream(sA);
      sA.SaveToStream(s);
      // s.CopyFrom(sA, sA.Size);
      // s.LoadFromStream(sA);
      s.Position := sA.Size;
    end;
    with DateED.spED_TemplateParagraf do
    begin
      First;
      while not EOF do
      begin
        DateED.BlobField.SaveToStream(sP);
        sP.SaveToStream(s);
        s.Position := sP.Size;
        sP.Clear;
        Next;
      end;
    end;
    s.SaveToFile('D:\test.doc');
  finally
    sA.Free;
    s.Free;
    sP.Free;
  end;
```

For some reason this does not do the trick, anyone can help me with a suggestion? How can I concat my Blob fields?

**EDIT** :

So after trying David's solution

```
   procedure CopyBlobFieldToStream(ds: TDataSet; field: TBlobField; outputStream: TStream);
    var
      inputStream: TStream;
    begin
      inputStream := ds.CreateBlobStream(field, bmRead);
      try
        outputStream.CopyFrom(inputStream, inputStream.Size);
      finally
        inputStream.Free;
      end;
    end;

    ....

    stream := TFileStream.Create(fileName, fmCreate);
    try
      CopyBlobFieldToStream(ds, field1, stream);
      CopyBlobFieldToStream(ds, field2, stream);
    finally
      stream.Free;
    end;
```

I still can't find all the info from the fields into

```
var
  i: Int32;
  stream: TFileStream;
  Path1: string;
  WordApp: TWordApplication;
begin
  Path1 := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(GetEnvironmentVariable('TEMP')) +
    FormatDateTime('yyyymmddhhnnssz', Now) + '.doc';
  WordApp := TWordApplication.Create(nil);
  stream := TFileStream.Create(Path1, fmCreate);
  try
    try
      with dm do
      begin
        DataSet.First;
        CopyBlobFieldToStream(dm.DataSet,
          dm.DataSetBlobField, stream);
        ShowMessage(IntToStr(stream.Size));
        DataSet.Next;
        CopyBlobFieldToStream(dm.DataSet,
          dm.DataSetBlobField, stream);
        ShowMessage(IntToStr(stream.Size));
        CopyBlobFieldToStream(dm.DataSet2,
          dm.DataSet2BlobField, stream);
        ShowMessage(IntToStr(stream.Size));
      end;
    finally
      stream.Free;
    end;
    WordApp.Documents.Open(Path1, EmptyParam, False, EmptyParam, EmptyParam,
      EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam,
      EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
    WordApp.Visible := True;
  finally
    WordApp.Free;
  end;
```

This is the way I call, but in the Word dock I only find the text from the first blob field but indeed the stream size is increasing.

Comment: Why are you saving ANSI text to your database? If you are operating with text, isn't it easy just to work with strings? Why are you using string stream at all? Why are you storing ANSI text in a binary BLOB?

Comment: My Blob fields are in fact some word documents.

Comment: Binary BIFF8 documents then? Certainly not something that is appropriate for use with a string stream. This is binary data. Not text.

Comment: What should I use instead of StringStream and how can I concatate more blob fields into a stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string stream is the wrong tool for the job. You don't have text, you have binary data. You are simply looking to concatenate two binary BLOBs. Do that with code something along these lines:

```
procedure ConcatenateBlobField(ds: TDataSet; field1, field2: TBlobField; outputStream: TStream);
var
  inputStream: TStream;
begin
  inputStream := ds.CreateBlobStream(field1, bmRead);
  try
    outputStream.CopyFrom(inputStream, inputStream.Size);
  finally
    inputStream.Free;
  end;

  inputStream := ds.CreateBlobStream(field2, bmRead);
  try
    outputStream.CopyFrom(inputStream, inputStream.Size);
  finally
    inputStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

In order to save to a file, create a `TFileStream` and pass it to the function.

```
stream := TFileStream.Create(fileName, fmCreate);
try
  ConcatenateBlobFields(ds, field1, field2, stream);
finally
  stream.Free;
end;
```

Or perhaps like this:

```
procedure CopyBlobFieldToStream(ds: TDataSet; field: TBlobField; outputStream: TStream);
var
  inputStream: TStream;
begin
  inputStream := ds.CreateBlobStream(field, bmRead);
  try
    outputStream.CopyFrom(inputStream, inputStream.Size);
  finally
    inputStream.Free;
  end;
end;

....

stream := TFileStream.Create(fileName, fmCreate);
try
  CopyBlobFieldToStream(ds, field1, stream);
  CopyBlobFieldToStream(ds, field2, stream);
finally
  stream.Free;
end;
```

Comment: TStream won't let me SaveToFile the content.

Comment: OK, I thought you wanted to concatenate two BLOBs to a third BLOB. You want to write the two BLOBs into a stream. My update does that.

Comment: something is not working... stream output is only what was in the first Blob field.  Thank you anyways for trying.

Comment: It's more likely that you are doing something wrong. How would the code in the answer not do what was intended? How would it fail to read from the second BLOB. Do you understand the code yet?

Comment: Yes I do understand the code, maybe is something wrong with my data, i'll come back with an answer as soon as I have it.

Comment: You've now got a different problem. The code I provide does indeed concatenate your two BLOBs. That is clear since the stream size increases. But you do not concatenate two Word documents by simply concatenating the .doc files. So whilst I believe I have answered the question you asked, I'm afraid you asked the wrong question! You need to know how to concatenate two Word documents.

Comment: Well I thought that concatenating two BLOBs that contain two Word documents, but looks like it doesn't. I'll investigate more. THank you!

Comment: Take two .doc files on the disk. Concatenate them using a command line tool such as `cat.exe`. You'll see that this does not concatenate the documents.